# Play video frame by frame in react native expo-av

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I am struggling to make a frame by frame video player using `expo-av`.

This is what I actually do:

- parse video infos with `ffmpeg-kit-react-native` (`FFprobeKit.getMediaInformation(src)`)
- calculate manually the frame length
- when pressing the 'next frame' button, I update video position with`video.setPositionAsync(position + frameRateLength, { toleranceMillisBefore: 0, toleranceMillisAfter: 0 })`

While this is ok for most 30fps video, it is actually very buggy when reading video taken from an iPhone at a high frame rate. I think this is because they have a variable frame rate.

Being able to parse correctly high frame rates is actually what I want my app to do, so i there a way to get around this problem using `expo-av` or another video library for react native ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try generating thumbnails with `expo-video-thumbnails` instead of using ffmpeg, there is a method that lets you extract thumbnails at a specific time in milliseconds, so it's quite precise, you can then display the thumbnails as pictures instead of using AV player.

For example if you want a frame every 16ms (approx 60fps)

```
let thumbnailsArray =[];
for (let i=0, i<yourVideoLength/16, i++) {
  const { uri } = await VideoThumbnails.getThumbnailAsync(yourVideoUrl,{time: 16*i});
  thumbnailsArray.push(uri);
}
```